# Create folder or open it if exists using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, mapi, ews-managed-api

We are migrating our application from MAPI to EWS Managed API. In MAPI we can create new folder or open it if it exists using the single MAPI method IMAPIFolder::CreateFolder.

But I cannot find such functionality in EWS. 
I can create folder like this (but it throws exception if such folder already exists in target folder):

```cs
var newFolder = new Folder(service);
newFolder.DisplayName = "name";
newFolder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Root);
```

or open(find) it like this

```cs
var filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "name");
service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, filter, new FolderView(1));
```

I.e. I must catch this exception and find folder using ExchangeService.FindFolders method. All this looks super weird. And the worst thing is what we must using this both EWS calls in such cases.

Is it possible to use single EWS call to get "CreateOrOpen" functionalty? Maybe build EWS Request manually or ?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing similar issue, For every operation we need to make a EWS service call.I did not find any EWS service method to perform both(Create & Open) functionality. So I comprised with performance and making multiple calls as below.

```
bool isExists = ews.FolderExists(EwsFolderId.Root, "name");
if (!isExists){
    ews.CreateFolder(EwsFolderId.Root, "name");
 }else{
     //Find folder or get folder code goes here
  }
```